# Disable past dates in a picker

Tags: codenameone

How can I disable past dates in the picker? I want the users to choose only the future dates. So what I want is to disable the current date and all the past date so that one can only choose the date from tomorrow.

```
Picker datePicker = new Picker();
datePicker.setUIID("small");
datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Picker` class doesn't allow you to set the min or max dates.  You can file an RFE on this in the CN1 issue tracker.

The `Spinner` class, however, does allow you to set a minimum and maximum date.  `Spinner` is marked deprecated since we try to encourage use of `Picker` when applicable - mainly because it uses the platform's native picker widget when available, and generally results in better UX.  In certain cases, like this, you can fall back to Spinner and it should still be fine.

Comment: Steve, how to disable future dates from the Calendar in Codename One?

Comment: Rafa, i advice you to do a small controle to the selected date, if it is in the future just prompt some message